I have a four gang box with four separate Switches. All work except for one
I recently installed a four gang box with four different switches for four different things. One is for The ceiling lights, Which is a three-way switch. One Is for the exhaust fan. One is the vanity light. And one is a light over top the shower. All of them work except for the shower. Light wire is hot, but the light does not come on. I thought it may have been the switch. I replaced it, still nothing. any suggestions? What could be done to fix this problem?

Check the neutral at the light. If it's connected properly there check in the switch box.
